# OpenMP data races without a collapse clause?

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

I'm learning OpenMP and faced a weird (to me) issue with the collapse clause. My actual code is a lot longer than this, but I was able to reproduce my issue using this short version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    size_t nrows = 10, ncols = 10;
    unsigned int *cells;
    int row, col;

    cells = calloc(nrows * ncols, sizeof *cells);

#pragma omp parallel for
    for (row = 0; row < nrows; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < ncols; col++)
            if (row * col % 10)
                cells[row * nrows + col] = 1;
    }

    for (row = 0; row < nrows; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < ncols; col++)
            printf("%d ", cells[row * nrows + col]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I get the expected output using one thread `OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 ./test`:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

and its md5sum is `94ae20845c84c865dbea94918ac5f06e`. Now, if I run it using more than one thread many times, it sometimes generates different results.

```bash
$ for i in `seq 1 100`; do OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 ./test | md5sum; done | sort -u
94ae20845c84c865dbea94918ac5f06e *-
b1123bcfe82797548237998874cd0fd5 *-
```

What's more interesting? If I add `collapse(2)` to `parallel for`, I get the expected output consistently.

I also tried:

```c
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (row = 0; row < nrows; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < ncols; col++)
            if (row * col % 10)
#pragma omp atomic write
                cells[row * nrows + col] = 1;
#pragma omp flush
    }
```

but it didn't help.

My only *uneducated* theory is that without `collapse(2)`, after each `col` for loop, a second thread somehow overwrites the result of its previous thread with its initial 0 cell values, which it never touched because each thread updates its own portion of the `cells` array (`row * nrows + col` is unique). Is it false sharing because multiple threads try to access cells close to each other? Then, why does it only happen without `collapse(2)` and is it still safe with `collapse(2)`?

FYI, I used MinGW GCC from MSYS2.

The reason why I want to parallelize the outer loop only is the cost of collapsing with dynamic scheduling. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Always declare your loop variables in the loop header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR answer:** You have a data race on variable `col`, which does not occur if you use the `collapse(2)` clause because it privatizes both loop variables.

**Details**: You have to examine the [sharing attributes](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu106.html) of your loop variables(`row` and `col`) to understand what is happening here.

If `collapse(2)` clause is not used

```
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (row = 0; row < nrows; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < ncols; col++)
```

the sharing attribute of variable `row` is private, because loop variables are implicitly privatized. Variable `col`, however, is shared. It means that different threads use the same variable (memory location) creating a race condition. That is the reason you sometimes obtain unexpected results.

On the other hand, if the `collapse(2)` clause is used, both loop variables are privatized, so there is no race condition, and you always obtain the correct result.

To fix your code (without using the `collapse(2)` clause) you have to make `col` private. To do so you have 2 alternatives:

a) The preferred method is to define your variables in their minimum required scope. Note that variables declared in the parallel region are private by default.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (size_t row = 0; row < nrows; row++) {
        for (size_t col = 0; col < ncols; col++)
```

b) the alternative is to explicitly use the `private` clause:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(col)
    for (row = 0; row < nrows; row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < ncols; col++)
```

Note that line `cells[row * nrows + col] = 1;` is free from data race, so atomic operation and `flush` are not necessary.

Comment: That was it! Thanks for the help! The above example doesn't need atomic or flush operations, but my actual code needs data synchronization (writing to its own, but reading from other threads' locations). In this case, is `flush` just before reading shared data enough instead of `atomic write` and `atomic read` pairs? In one of OpenMP examples, they used both (https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu96.html).

Comment: No, `flush` construct does not make your operation atomic. This is a quite complex topic. I advise you not to use the `flush` construct at all. All books and even the specification say "Use of a flush construct with a list is extremely error prone and users are strongly discouraged from attempting it. " My suggestion is to use `atomic read seq_cst` or `atomic write seq_cst`.

Comment: or in more complex cases you can use locks (i.e. `#pragma omp critical`)

Comment: Thanks for the hints! I just tried `atomic read` and `atomic write` without `seq_cst` and data races occurred occasionally (so not reliable). When I used `flush` just before reading shared data (but not after writing), there were no data races. Now, I'm testing `atomic read/write seq_cst`. Could you please explain how exactly `seq_cst` works to prevent data races?

Comment: First of all, just because your program produces correct results does not mean that your parallel code is correct. Even if your compiler generates correct machine code, your C/C++ code can still be flawed. Using a different compiler or CPU can result in completely different outcomes. This is why testing multithreaded code is such a challenging task.

Comment: The C++11 memory models are a complex topic and cannot be explained in a single comment. I recommend reading a decent book on the subject and OpenMP. The main point is that using the `seq_cst` memory order clause includes an implicit strong flush and prevents the compiler/CPU from freely reorganizing your code/instructions. This ensures the correct order of operations, which is important in the case of communicating between threads. My suggestion is to always use `seq_cst` memory order instead of the default (`relaxed`).